# How to find installed user of msi?

Tags: wix, installation, registry, windows-installer, powershell-2.0

We need to find the user who has installed msi using powershell.

I was trying to search via HKEY_USERS ,but it is providing sid of the user not the user name of who installed the msi.

Is there any way to find the Installed user ?

Comment: If the user is a domain user you can convert SID to sAMAccountName easily

Answer (score 3):

(If you have a sid, you can find out the user name, why not?)

But the best way, if the msi is yours, is to save that information during the setup in a registry value, or .ini file you can read out later.
There are two properties, "LogonUser", and "USERNAME", the latter is the user really installing.

If you have no influence on the msi itself, I am not sure, if it is so easy. Interpreting sids seems a good way then.

Nevertheless:

The standard way is to use the API routines MsiGetProductInfo() or MsiGetProductInfoEx(). You can google in MSDN. But I am not sure if they always contain information if these data were not registered during setup dialog. So maybe they are empty after a silent install if there was no registration dialog? I have never used them to find the user who has installed as software. Normally in own setups this is done with explicit dialogs or actions.

Answer (score 1):

One of the way might be by using `reg key`   but there is a function in the windows installer API called [MsiEnumProductsEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

you have to specify User SID it querys and checks all installed product for all users